# Nonlinear differential equation with power nonlinearity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to solve the foolowing equation
$$y''(x) + f(x)y(x) - \frac{1}{{y(x)}} = 0$$
where $f(x)$ is some defined (and 'well behaved') function.
Of course, if $f(x) = {\text{const}}$, equation can be solved easy enough, because it's autonomous. But I can't find a way to solve it even with some simply $f(x)$ like $f(x)=x$ ane etc.
Any help?

Comment: Look up the Airy equation, even without the third term such an equation usually has no symbolic solution.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I thought solution in the form (for example)
if we know solution of equation $y''(x) + f(x)y(x)=0$, we can solve (or simplify) the original equation

Comment: @Msdos4 If you study a perturbation expansion of the equation: $y''+fy-\epsilon/y=0$, then the 'unperturbed' ($\epsilon=0$) equation is the one in your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similarly to the the Yermakov equation, you can make two substitutions to arrive at a possibly simpler equation. If $\lambda(x)$ is a non-trivial solution to the equation $\color{blue}{\lambda''+f(x)\lambda=0}$, let $y=\lambda u$,
\begin{align}
\lambda^2uu''+2\lambda\lambda'uu'+\color{blue}{(\lambda''+f(x)\lambda)}u=1.
\end{align}
Then taking $x(t)$ the equation becomes, (via the chain rule, where $\dot u=\mathrm du/\mathrm dt$),
\begin{align}
(\lambda t')^2u\ddot u+\color{red}{(\lambda^2t')'}u\dot u=1.
\end{align}
By taking
\begin{align}
t=\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\lambda^2}
\end{align}
the part in red becomes zero, giving
\begin{align}
u\ddot u=\lambda(t)^2.
\end{align}
If this were a Yermakov equation, it would have been reduced to a similar autonomous equation after these two transformations, but I'm afraid yours does not turn out so nicely following the same procedure. Perhaps this is what you were thinking of in your comment?